# What is the scheduling mechanism using by Ubuntu core

Tags: ubuntu-core

What is the scheduling mechanism using by Ubuntu core. Is it Completely Fair Scheduler(CFS) ??

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Man Pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man7/sched.7.html):

```
Since  Linux  2.6.23,  the default scheduler is CFS, the "Completely Fair Scheduler".  
The CFS scheduler replaced the earlier "O(1)" scheduler.
```